# Is `typedef` of a function standard C syntax, and how does it differ from a `typedef` of a function pointer?

Tags: c, visual-c++

Function pointers are often declared using `typedef` in C programs:

```
typedef int (*PFN_RETURNING_INT)(int, int);
```

The `*` indicates that this a pointer, to a function taking two `int` arguments and returning `int`.

I was digging around the Windows SDK header files and found this in `rpcdec.h` after running it through the C preprocessor:

```
typedef void __stdcall
RPC_INTERFACE_GROUP_IDLE_CALLBACK_FN (
      RPC_INTERFACE_GROUP IfGroup,
      void* IdleCallbackContext,
      unsigned long IsGroupIdle
    );
```

Note there is no `*` to indicate "pointerness". It seems to define a typedef to a *function*, not a *pointer* to a function. I was under the impression that functions are not first-class entities in the C type system, so I'm confused as how to understand the typedef.

When I define a function with a parameter of type `RPC_INTERFACE_GROUP_IDLE_CALLBACK_FN`, the MSVC compiler happily accepts it and appears to treat it like *pointer* to a function.

Is the `typedef` valid C? Should I be interpreting the `typedef` as defining a name to a *pointer*  a function?

EDIT:
I tinkered some more with the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*PFN)(int x);
typedef void FN(int x);

void print(int x)
{
    printf("%d\n", x);
}

void doit(FN fn)
{
    fn(3);
}

void doit_p(PFN pfn)
{
    pfn(3);
}

int main ()
{
    doit(print);
    doit_p(print);
    // FN x = print;    // Uncommenting these two lines fails to compile.
    // doit(x);
    exit(0);
}
```

Interestingly, the compiler happily accepts the program, but if I uncomment the two lines in `main`, it complains with "`initialization of a function`". It reminds me of the behaviour of array parameters in C, which "decay" to pointers. But is this bevaviour intentional, or accidental?

Comment: What do you mean by "first-class?"  As I understand C, you need a pointer to *pass* a function, but not to declare one.

Comment: That's the source of my confusion. What is the typedef defining: a name alias to a function or a name alias to a pointer to a function? Normally there is a `*` involved in a pointer declaration, but the sample I see has none.

Comment: this syntax is valid since the dawn of in in 70s, but still it is relatively unknown and non-idiomatic. For example rather than declaring `int foo(void); int bar(void);` one can do `typedef int F(void); F foo, bar;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> … I was under the impression that functions are not first-class entities in the C type system, so I'm confused as how to understand the typedef.

A `typedef` declares a name for a type. It does not declare a function or other entity, nor does it pass a function or otherwise use a function in an expression, so it does not matter whether a function is a first-class entity: The name simply identifies the type, and that does not require the type to be a first-class type.

> When I define a function with a parameter of type…

A declaration of a parameter as a function is automatically adjusted to be a declaration of a pointer to a function. C 2018 6.7.6.3 8 says:

> A declaration of a parameter as “function returning *type*” shall be adjusted to “pointer to function returning *type*”, as in 6.3.2.1.

Also, when a function designator is used in an expression other than as the operand of unary `&`, it is automatically converted to a pointer to the function, per C 2018 6.3.2.1 4:

> A *function designator* is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator [which fails because applying `sizeof` to a function is a constraint violation], or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type “function returning *type*” is converted to an expression that has type “pointer to function returning *type*”.

Comment: I knew someone would have an answer from the C specification.  Alas, I have never found the time to digest the 500-plus pages.

Comment: That's the missing piece: "...shall be adjusted...". I can now proceed with my own C parser handling this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

typedef(s) introduce synonyms or in other words aliases for different types. Functions have types. So you may use a typedef declaration to introduce an alias for a function type.

Here is a simple example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int Func( int, int );

Func f;

int f( int x, int y )
{
    return x + y;
}

int main( void )
{
    Func *fp = f;

    printf( "%d + %d = %d\n", 5, 5, fp( 5, 5 ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this definition is valid. You may have to use `*` when using the definition :

```
void __stdcall my callback(
      RPC_INTERFACE_GROUP IfGroup,
      void* IdleCallbackContext,
      unsigned long IsGroupIdle
    );



RPC_INTERFACE_GROUP_IDLE_CALLBACK_FN  *pointer_to_function = &my_callback;
```